# Suddenly manim doesnt run

Tags: manim, algorithm-animation

I've installed manim recently and run many animations so far, but a few hours ago I realized that even the simplest code that used to run no longer does. I must have messed up somewhere without realizing it... This is what I get every time:

```
AttributeError: module 'manimlib' has no attribute 'constants'
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Not a master on this topic, but there is a file named 'constants.py' inside the manimlib folder that can be possibly missing or damaged... try replacing it with the original one: https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/master/manimlib/constants.py